# Email does not attach file

Tags: objective-c, ios, csv, email-attachments

I'm using the below code to send a `csv` via email. The email is send and I received in my Inbox, but I'm not receiving the `csv` file attached, any idea about what is wrong?

```
-(void)generateCSV
{
NSFileManager *filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
NSArray *dirPaths;
NSString *docsDir;

dirPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                               NSUserDomainMask, YES);
docsDir = [dirPaths objectAtIndex:0];

if ([filemgr fileExistsAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.csv", docsDir] ] == NO)
{
    [filemgr createFileAtPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.csv", docsDir] contents:[@"" dataUsingEncoding: NSUnicodeStringEncoding] attributes: nil];
}

surveyarray = [db retrieveSurvey];

CHCSVWriter * csvWriter = [[CHCSVWriter alloc] initWithCSVFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.csv", docsDir] atomic:NO];

NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"No, CreatedDate, Question1, Question2, Question3, Comment\n"];
[csvWriter writeField:str];

for(int i = 0; i < surveyarray.count; i++)
{
    survey = [surveyarray objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@\n", i,  survey.createddate, survey.question1, survey.question2, survey.question3, survey.comment];
    [csvWriter writeField:str];
}

NSMutableString *subject = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSMutableString *emailBody = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

[subject appendString:@""];

MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;

[mailer setSubject:subject];

NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", nil];
[mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.csv", docsDir]];
NSLog(@"%@", myData);

[mailer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"test.csv"];

[mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;

[self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];

[mailer release];
[subject release];
[emailBody release];

[csvWriter release];
}
```

I am generating `csv` file then send email as attachment.

I open the email in my mailbox, it does not content any attachment.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

finally I solved the problem. The email did attached attachment just the file is empty. This is because the for loop initial with -1 and i change to int i = 0, it works fine now

Answer (score 0):

According to what I see [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677004/email-csv-file-with-mfmailcomposer), I'd say that you forgot to add `.csv` at the end of your filename :)

Comment: Yes he did. But that should not do much harm at all. If that were the only issue then the data shold be properly attached to the email. Only on reception in his mail client when saving the attachment, the default file name is "test" and not "test.csv".

Answer (score 0):

According to the NSData class reference, the path given with dataWithContentsOfFile: should be the absolute path. So you should use

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.csv", docsDir]
```

instead of just `@"test.csv"`

I bet currently your `myData` is nil or empty.

By the way, I would create an NSString object with the fully qualified path/filename only once and re-use that rather than creating it 3 or 4 times.

Comment: I had edited the code but yet still failed to get and i try to log the nsdata, reutnr `<>`

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me every time!

```
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865
```

Answer (score -1):

try replacing above line this

```
[mailer addAttachmentData:myData mimeType:@"text/csv" fileName:@"test.csv"];
```

Comment: Yes you can. It is a sub-type of text. See http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/text/index.html

Comment: replacing @"test" with @"test.csv" helps?

Comment: It is certainly an improvement but does not fix the issue of the missing attachment.