# iPhone: email attachment not available on recipient's side

Tags: objective-c, file, csv, email-attachments

I'm trying to send a file but when I open the received email, the attached file has disappeared, well, just one, because the image is there.
The file format is text/plain, with .csv extension. Working on the simulator, I can open and read the file with no problem at all. Once installed the app on the iPhone (iOS 7) or on the iPad (iOS 6.1), the file is attached to the email, but, as I said before, the file disappears somewhere before getting to the recipient.
iPhone screen capture:
[image: iphone Screen Capture]

When I open the email on my computer:
[image: Mail screen capture]

Code I'm using to write and load the file:

```
- (IBAction)buttonSendData:(id)sender {
   
    if ([self checkUIPicker])
    
    {
        //fetching data
    
        COAppDelegate *appDelegate = (COAppDelegate *)  [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
        NSError *error;
  
        NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Tiempos" inManagedObjectContext:context];
        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc ]init];

        [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    
        NSPredicate *sectionAndControl = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(tramo == %@) AND (control == %@)", section, control];
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:sectionAndControl];
    
        NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc]initWithKey:@"dorsal" ascending:YES];
        [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor ]];
    
        dorsalesPorTramoYcontrol = [context executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    
        if (!dorsalesPorTramoYcontrol || !dorsalesPorTramoYcontrol.count) {
            UIAlertView *alertFail = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Atención" message:@"No hay registros que cumplan esos criterios" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
            [alertFail show];
            
        }
    }
        if (dorsalesPorTramoYcontrol && dorsalesPorTramoYcontrol.count )
            {
                NSMutableString *mainString = [[ NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@"dorsal,paso,tiempo\n"];

                for (NSManagedObject *get in dorsalesPorTramoYcontrol) {
            
                     //dorsales
                    NSString *string =[get valueForKey:@"dorsal"];
                    [mainString appendFormat:@"%@,",string];
                    
                    //paso
                    string = [get valueForKey:@"paso"];
                    string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
                    [mainString appendFormat:@"%@,",string];

                    
                    //tiempo
                    string = [get valueForKey:@"tiempo"];
                    string=[string stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\"\""];
                    [mainString appendFormat:@"%@",string];

                    //new line
                    [mainString appendFormat:@"\n"];
                    
                    
             }
                
                NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
                NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
                file = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/Tramo#%@_Control#%@.csv",section,control]];
                
                NSData *settingsData;
                settingsData = [mainString dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
                
                if ([settingsData writeToFile:file atomically:YES]) {
                    NSLog(@"writing Ok");
                    
                    [self composeEmail];
                    }
            }
        
}

-(void)composeEmail{
    
    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
    {
        
        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        [mailer setSubject:[NSString   stringWithFormat:@"Resultados Tramo: %@ - Control: %@", section, control]];
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"turkish@mundo-r.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];
        
        //Clasicos Ourense Logo
        UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"clasicosOurense.png"];
        NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(myImage);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"Icon"];
        
        //file attachment
        // Determine the file name and extension
        NSArray *filepart = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
        NSString *filename = [filepart objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *extension = [filepart objectAtIndex:1];
        
        // Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
        NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:extension];
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
        
        // Add attachment
        [mailer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/plain" fileName:filename];
        
        NSString *emailBody =
        [NSString   stringWithFormat:@"Resultados Tramo: %@ - Control: %@ \nDorsal - Paso - Tiempo", section, control];
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet;
        [self presentViewController:mailer animated:YES completion:nil];
    }
    else
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Failure"
                                                        message:@"Your device doesn't support the composer sheet"
                                                       delegate:nil
                                              cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                              otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}



-(BOOL) checkUIPicker{
    
    if ((control.length == 0) || (section.length == 0))
    {
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Atención" message:@"Escoge un tramo y un control horario" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        return NO;
        
    }else if ((!control.length==0) && (!section.length==0 ))   {
        UIAlertView *alertSend = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Atención" message:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Vas a enviar la información correspondiente al control: %@ del tramo: %@", control, section] delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Correcto" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertSend show];
        return YES;
    }

    return NO;
}

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error
{
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }
    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

Where is the failure?
Thank you!

Comment: Hope you have specified correct mime type. If its incorrect , it won't be received at other end.

Answer (score 0):

`NSData` was `null`.

Simpler things are better. Using the code provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10677004/email-csv-file-with-mfmailcomposer) to attach a csv file, it works now.

#### Replaced:

```
//file attachment
// Determine the file name and extension
NSArray *filepart = [file componentsSeparatedByString:@"."];
NSString *filename = [filepart objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *extension = [filepart objectAtIndex:1];

// Get the resource path and read the file using NSData
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename 
                                                     ofType:extension];
NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];

// Add attachment
[mailer addAttachmentData:fileData mimeType:@"text/plain" 
                                   fileName:filename];
```

#### by:

```
[mailer addAttachmentData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:file] mimeType:@"text/csv" 
                                                               fileName:file];
```